# Не работает файл css в python django

Tags: javascript, python, css, django

Делаю темную тему для шаблона в проекте `Django`.

У меня есть базовый шаблон, находящийся в отдельной папке **layout**.

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <!-- другие link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'CSS/light.css' %}" id="theme">

    <title>Color battle</title>
</head>


<body>
    {% block home %}

    {% endblock %}
</body>

<script src="{% static 'JS/scripting.js' %}"></script>
</html>
```

`light.html` - основной шаблон, который находится в другой папке и меняется на шаблон `dark.html` при нажатии на кнопку в `profile.html`.

```
 <div>
       <button id="switchMode">Меняй</button>
</div>
```

К кнопке подключен `script.js`

```
let switchMode = document.getElementById("switchMode");

switchMode.onclick = function () {
    let theme = document.getElementById("theme");

    if (theme.getAttribute("href") == "light.css") {
        theme.href = "dark.css";
    } else {
        theme.href = "light.css";
    }
}
```

Скрипт принимается, и `light.css` отображает `profile.html` со всеми стилями, но после нажатия на кнопку все стили пропадают и выводится ошибка (**Vanilin_Ivanov** - имя пользователя)

> Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/Vanilin_Ivanov/dark.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Я знаю, что это говорит о том, что **css**-файл не найдет, но он же правильно подключен и отображает стили, что делать?

Comment: Это совсем не говорит о том, что css файл не найден. Вы текст ошибки точно понимаете?

Comment: Здравствуйте, во многих ответах по этой ошибке пишется именно про неправильном указании пути, так в чем же проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Что то подобное было. Джанго не видел ни css ни js.
В итоге решил этот вопрос с помощью изменения подключения статики в settings.py
Попробуйте этот код, я свой закоментил, вставил этот код и вуаля все мои изменения в статике заработали и все начало работать. Даже потом, когда я снова свой стандартный код раскоментил, а это подключение стаики убрал, все уже работало.
Надеюсь поможет комуто. Мне так помогло. Отпишитесь кому поможет.

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'static',
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

На сколько я понял, `BASE_DIR` дает нам каталог нашего проекта. Поэтому, когда мы делаете `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject/static')`, это становится `myproject/myproject/static`.
Или '/static'), надо указывать 'static/'),или попробуйте так '/').

Надеюсь поможет комуто. Мне так помогло. Отпишитесь кому поможет.